# Can't login to mysql community server

Tags: mysql

I downloaded mysql for the first time and created a password and login and done something.

After the first restart of computer it started showing me errors when I tried to login with the exact same password.

```
unknown OS character set 'cp857'.
switching to the default character set 'utf8mb4'.
```

Answer (score 0):

Change encoding according to your MySql server. Here you can see a list of [chcp codes](https://ss64.com/nt/chcp.html) and the correlated country/region languages.

Ex: for European-Latin

You can change code page permanantly as follows:

- Start -> Run -> regedit
- Go to [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor]
- Add new String Value named: Autorun
- Change the value to 'chcp [chcp_code]'

This is not the first time I see issues with turkish...

Answer (score 0):

You can tell mysql your default character-set in your my.cnf configuration file. Just have to add lines to define collation and character set. For example you can try something general like:

```
collation_server = utf8_unicode_ci
character_set_server = utf8
```

Or maybe something more specific:

```
collation_server = latin5_turkish_ci
character_set_server = latin5
```

And then restart your mysql server.

Note: This doesn't need to be done in the registry, as @Simo stated.